# When does an app receive the INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast?

Tags: android, google-play

When exactly does an app receive an `INSTALL_REFERRER` broadcast from Android Market? Can I safely assume it's received before `Application.onCreate()` is called? I want to make sure my app doesn't dispatch any tracking to Google Analytics before it is received. Put another way, where is the best place to put my tracking code? I am only tracking installs.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I safely assume it's received before Application.onCreate() is called

It is guaranteed that `Application.onCreate()` will be called before any broadcast is received.

> I want to make sure my app doesn't dispatch any tracking to Google Analytics before it is received. Put another way, where is the best place to put my tracking code?

Presumably in an `IntentService` triggered by your `INSTALL_REFERER` `BroadcastReceiver`, if you do not want to do the work before the broadcast is received.